Keycloak email verification mail sending manually?
Im trying to manually send email verification mail using this API
/{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email

But it does not work, here you can check their documentation 
On second screenshot you can see how Im sending request (in body I have actions parameter) and as you can see Im receiving error 400
But if I will send the request with empty body, then it works
The problem is it triggers all kind of required actions and thats not acceptable.
What to do?

Simply use
[
    "VERIFY_EMAIL"
]

as body
